# How can I modify this Powershell script to combine two files

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for help modifying the following PowerShell script, so that it combines two files from two different folders - both with the same filenames but different extensions (one .txt and one .dat) - then outputs into a third folder with the .dat extension.

The current script uses header.txt and joins this to each file in sequence from the input folder, then sends this joined file to the output folder.

For example:

header.txt + 01.dat (input folder) = 01.dat (output folder)

header.txt + 02.dat (input folder) = 02.dat (output folder)
...

I need this script to read different files from each folder and then output this into the output folder.

For example;

header01.txt (header folder) + 01.dat (input folder) = 01.dat (output folder)

header02.txt (header folder) + 02.dat (input folder) = 02.dat (output folder)
...

Can anyone help?

```
$baseFilename = "c:\temp\header.txt"
$addonFolderLocation = "c:\temp\input\"
$combinedFolderLocation = "c:\temp\output\"

#Get all files in addon folder location

$addonFilenames = Get-ChildItem $addonFolderLocation

foreach ($addonFilename in $addonFilenames)

{
    cmd /c copy /b $baseFilename + $addonFilename.fullname "$combinedFolderLocation $addonFilename"
        }
```

Comment: Can you add more specific example paths for the input/output folder path structure? Like are `header01.txt` and `header02.txt` in the same folder? Are those the exact file names with a matching number?

Comment: You need to study joins a little more completely.  In particular, you need to explore the difference between a cartesian join and an equijoin.  Literature on relational databases should help.

Comment: In addition to joins, there is another way a process can combine two files.  Look up template engines.  Template engines draw information about the form of the result from a template, and information about the content of the result from a data file.